# Geometry question with tangent lines and two circles

Tags: geometry

I have the following here:

> Two poles with radii of $18$cm and $7$cm are connected by a single metal band joining their centres and points of their outer edges. This is shown below.

[image: Description of question]

> Determine the length of the metal band that is needed, if AB is tangent to both poles.

I have no idea how to proceed. I know $AO$ and $BC$ are tangent at $A$ and $B$ respectively but aside from getting a hypotenuse, I'm not really sure how else to procees. The answer is supposedly $146$cm but I am not sure how that was found.

I know we add $AO$, $OC$, $CB$ and $BA$ but I need to find $OC$ and I don't know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$OC$ is, by the Pythagorean theorem (drop perpendicular from $O$ to $BC$),
$$\sqrt{60^2+(18-7)^2}=61$$
The rest is trivial.